# Why does my text in firebase storage file in numbers instead of the intended strings?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

My code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,  TextInput} from 'react-native'
import React , { useState} from 'react'

import { storage} from '../firebase'
import { Button  } from '@rneui/themed';
import { uploadString } from 'firebase/storage';
import { ref as sRef } from 'firebase/storage';
import 'react-native-get-random-values'
import {v1} from 'uuid'

const Reviews = ({route}) => {
  const paramKey = route.params.paramKey1
  const paramKey1 = route.params.paramKey2
  console.log("Path: " + paramKey)
  console.log("Shop: " +paramKey1)
  const feedback = "Post"
  
  
 
  const [todoDatafb, setToDoDatafb] = useState("")
  
  const handlefb = async () => {
    const fb = sRef(storage, paramKey + `/${feedback + v1()}.txt`);
    uploadString(fb, todoDatafb).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded new feedback')
      
    })
  }    
  console.log(todoDatafb)
   
  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
       
       <Text style = {styles.header}>Shop Name</Text>
       <Text style = {styles.text}>{paramKey1}</Text>
       
      
       <View style={{
        borderBottomColor: 'black',
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        }}
      />
      
      <View style = {styles.inputContainer}> 
            <Text></Text>
            <Text>   Feedback:   <Button
                onPress = {handlefb}
                title = "Post"
                
                buttonStyle={{
                  backgroundColor: 'black',
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  borderColor: 'white',
                  borderRadius: 30,
              }}
              /></Text>
            
            <TextInput
                editable
                multiline
                numberOfLines={5}
                maxLength={500}
                placeholder = "Key in for any feedback for the shop" 
                value = {todoDatafb}
                onChangeText ={text => setToDoDatafb(text)}
                style = {styles.input} 
            />
            <Text>  Feedback by others:</Text>
      
        </View> 
  
    </View>
    
  )
}

export default Reviews
```

Upon successful posting:

My own console. Log for `todoDatafb`

[image]

In the firebase storage console. Successful storage of .txt file

[image]

But when I tried to download this .txt file, I dont get the string inside of "Awesome". Instead I get bunch of numbers:
[image]

Why is this happening? I see from a youtube guide about storing string. The .txt file contains words instead of numbers:

[image]

Update: Put `console.log(todoDatafb)` in the function `handlefb`

Code

```
const handlefb = async () => {
    const fb = sRef(storage, paramKey + `/${feedback + v1()}.txt`);
    console.log("Right before uploadString: " + todoDatafb)
    uploadString(fb, todoDatafb).then((snapshot) => {
      console.log('Uploaded new feedback')
      console.log("In uploadString: " + todoDatafb)
    })
  }
```

The logs appearing:

[image]

Comment: Those are the ASCII values of the `"Awesome"` string. I don't immediately see why it would write those though. Can you move the `console.log(todoDatafb)` into `handlefb`, right before the call to `uploadString` and see if it still logs `"Awesome"` that way?

Comment: Oh. But why would it change to ASCII values in this case? I am confused on this. As requested, I have move the ```console.log(todoDataFb)``` to the function ```handlefb```. I move one before the ```uploadString``` and one within ```uploadString```. I still get the log of 'Awesome'. But when I tried to download the file, it still become ASCII values and not the string ```Awesome``` @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I don't immediately see why it would write those, which is why I posted a comment instead of an answer. I hope somebody else spots where this problem comes from.

Comment: Oh okay. Is there some other way that I can try to upload this .txt file to see if it a differences? @FrankvanPuffelen